# How to group a list using linq c#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

The scenario I have is as follows:

I have the following data -

### ID, Name, Type, Location, GroupID

```
1, samename, Rock, New York, 12
2, samename, Jazz, Sydney, 12
3, samename, Rock, Sydney, 12
4, samename, Jazz, New York, 12    
5, name3, Opera House, Sydney, 14
6, name3, Opera House, London, 14
7, name2, Emirates, London, 13
```

And I would like to output it flattened based on the GroupID like below

### ID, Name, Place, Location, GroupID

```
1, samename, {Rock,Jazz}, {New York,Sydney}, 12
5, name3, Opera House, {Sydney,London}, 14
7, name2, Emirates, London, 13
```

This was really bad design that I have inherited - and I am trying to make it better.. without breaking the old code.

I believe the answer is something to do with SelectMany - but I can't work out the syntax - I've tried a few different ways.

my attempted solution - without flattening..

```
var q3 = Data.Where(b=>b.GroupID != null).GroupBy(x=> new { x.GroupID }, (key, group) => new 
{ 
  GroupID = key.GroupID,  
  Result =  group.Select(g=> new 
                         {                            
                           Type = g.Type, 
                           Location = g.Location,                                                  
                         }).ToList()
});
```

Comment: You are trying to do the opposite of flattening it.

Comment: What *did* you try? In any case, what you posted isn't "flattening", you are grouping by name then applying various aggregations ,eg Min for ID, flattening for place, locagion, min for GroupID

Comment: A simple loop with a dictionary by name could be the simplest and clearest approach

Comment: @ClaudioRedi not really. What you call "loop with a dictionary" produces exactly what `GroupBy` or `group by`. Then what?

Comment: is the list {Rock,Jazz} linked to {New York,Sydney}?  How will it reflect that Rock - New York exists, but what if there is London - Jazz, but no London - Rock - how will that be represented, or are the two lists just simple lists with no links between them?

Comment: Ok, just to clarify - when the entries are created e.g. 1-4, the user selects Rock and Jazz as the type of music, then Sydney and London as the location. And that creates 4 entries. The case of "no London - Rock" can't exist because of the way the data is created.

Comment: my solution doesn't flatten it at the moment - and i can't work out how- here is what i've done.. var q3 = LibMessageNames.Where(b=>b.GroupID != null).GroupBy(x=> new { x.GroupID }, (key, group) => new 
{ 
  GroupID = key.GroupID,  
  Result =  group.Select(g=> new 
                         {                            
                           Type = g.Type, 
                           Location = g.Location,                  
                         }).ToList()
});

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavo: Not sure if I follow why you say it won't work, I won't add my answer since he explicitly asked for a linq solution but if I have a dictionary where the key is the name and the values is the new complex object then I could fill it on a for loop.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi check the answer. Creating that dictionary is only the *second* call (GroupBy). The real problem is generating the result fields. Loops would result in code that is a *lot* uglier. You'd need a separate loop for each field, or you'd have to use the same LINQ methods for Min, selection, etc

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I feel the group by is more cryptic than a simple for loop but we're entering on a subjective field. Sometimes people ask for a linq solution only because you save 1 line of code... most of the time linq is great and the perfect solution but sometimes it generates unreadable code. Not sure why you say that I need a separated loop. In one iteration I add "Place" and "Location" to respective list on the new complex target object that I get from dictionary. Might be missing something on the question but in any case OP will be happy with solution from Slava Utesinov

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
 var q = Data.Where(b => b.GroupID != null).GroupBy((x) => x.GroupID).Select((y) => new
                {
                    GroupID = y.First().ID,
                    Name = string.Join(",", y.Select((k) => k.Name).Distinct()),
                    Type = string.Join(",", y.Select(( k) => k.Type).Distinct()),
                    Location = string.Join(",", y.Select(( k) => k.Location).Distinct()),
                });
```

If you want to load the columns dynamically,use this code:

```
        var q2 = Data.Where(b => b.GroupID != null).GroupBy((x) => x.GroupID).Select((y) => new
        {
            GroupID = y.First().ID,
            result = DynamicGroup(y)
        });

    private static string DynamicGroup(IGrouping<string,DataD> y)
    {
        string result=null;
        foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pInfo in typeof(DataD).GetProperties().Where(x=>x.Name!="GroupID" && x.Name!="ID"))
        {
            result += string.Format(" {0} ; ",string.Join(",", y.Select((k) => pInfo.GetValue(k, null)).Distinct()));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: A very succinct answer. This is great! the string.Join works :) - My table actually has 10 other columns - how can I bring add the rest of the columns to q - without having to name each column?

Comment: Yes, with Reflection.

Comment: Hi - this is a bit embarrasing - but I am using linq to entities, and i'm getting the following error. {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}  - I was testing using linqpad and linqtosql which was a bit silly on my part.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
var answer = data.GroupBy(x => x.GroupID).Select(x => new { 
     ID = x.Min(y => y.ID),
     Name = x.Select(y => y.Name).ToList(),
     Type = x.Select(y => y.Type).ToList(),
     Location = x.Select(y => y.Location).ToList(),
     GroupID = x.Key
}).ToList();
```

Comment: what does x.Min do?

Comment: It gives you Min ID from group, i.e. 1, 5 and 7 respectively, also you can get ID of first item via `x.First().ID`

Answer (score 4):

You use `SelectMany` if you have a sequence of elements that has a sequence of inner elements and you want to access all sequences of inner elements as one sequence.

`SelectMany` is similar to the following code:

```
List<InnerClass> result = new List<InnerClass>()

foreach (var outerElement in outerSequence)
{
    foreach (InnerClass innerElement in outerSequence.InnerSequence)
    {
        // note that InnerSequence is an IEnumerable in every InnerElement
        result.Add(innerElement);
    }
}
```

You want the opposite: you want to group several elements of your collection into a new sequence. All Names used in your source should result into one element with several fields:

- Name is the name of all elements with the same name
- Id is the lowest Id of all elements this Name
- Place is a sequence of all Type in your sequence with this Name (rock, jazz, emirates) (a bit unlucky name)
- Location is the sequence of all Locations with Name
- GroupId is the GroupId of the items with Name

In your example a Name corresponds with a GroupId. Are you sure there can't be two elements with "samename" and different GroupId?

The first step is to group all elements with the same name using GroupBy:

var result1 = sourceCollection.GroupBy(sourceElement => sourceElement.Name);

Now you have a collection of `IGrouping` items, each `IGrouping` item is a sequence of source elements with the same Name, each `IGrouping` item has a Key property containing this mutual Name.

The second step is to transfer all elements in each group into sequences of Id, sequences of Place and Sequences of GroupId:

```
var result2 = result1.Select(group => new
{
    Name = group.Key,
    AllIds = group.Select(groupElement => groupElement.Id),
    Places = group.Select(groupElement => groupElement.Place),
    Locations = group.Select(groupElement => groupElement.Location),
    GroupIds = group.Selelect(groupElement => groupElement.GroupId),
};
```

"From every group in result1, make one new object with a property Name, which contains the Key of the group (which is the common name in all groupElements). This created object also has a property Places, which is from every element in the group the Place. Each create object also has a property Locations, which is... etc."

Now all you have to do is to get the lowest value from AllIds, and the one and only value from Groupids:

```
var result3 = result2.Select(item => new
{
    Name = item.Name,
    LowestId = item.AllIds.Orderby(id => id).First(),
    Places = item.Places,
    Locations = item.Locations,
    OneAndOnlyGroupId = item.GroupId.First(),
};
```

If you are not certain that all element with the same Name have the same GroupId, consider grouping by `new {Name = sourceElement.Name, GrouId = sourceElement.GroupId)`, to create groups with same `{Name, GroupId}`, or let your final `OneAndOnlyGroupId` be a sequence if `GroupIds`

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I like the thorough explanation as well. However I had to mark the other one as the anser.